# How do I install Qt in specified location?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, installation

I have just downloaded Qt 5.2.0 setup from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads). There's a strange problem that comes when I try to install it in "Program Files" directory under Windows.

[image]

The error message says:

> The installation path must not contain [~<>|?*!@#$%^&:,;], please
>   specify a valid folder.

I don't see any invalid characters in the path to my program files. How come I cannot install it?

Comment: I had no trouble installing it recently to a different drive.  Did you change the install directory from 'Program Files (x86)`?  It seems like a permissions issue, is the account you're installing under able to elevate to Administrator?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I actually ran the program under Administrator privileges. However, I tried `Program Files (x86)` but still the same thing shows up.

Answer (score -1):

There is a space between "Program" and "Files". If you remove the spaces form the path, it should work.

Comment: Right. There's also a space in `Qt 5.2.0` named folder.

Comment: @cpx have you tried to install it in a path without spaces? If so, did it work?

Comment: I'm not sure if removing the space would let me install in Program Files directory. Instead it would create another directory known as `ProgramFiles`

Comment: I usually build the Qt source code from scratch and download QtCreator. You should also be able to do this on Windows. This way you won't depend on the installer.

Answer (score -1):

There's a way to install Qt in a path with a space, by creating a symbolic link in the filesystem.

First you run `mklink /d "C:\Qt" "C:\Program Files\Qt"` in cmd.

Then run the QT Installer, and install into C:\Qt - it's actually in C:\Program Files\Qt

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you cannot use an address that has a blank space inside it that in this address you use of "strong textProgram Files"